How to plot a scatterplot and function in the same figure?
I've been trying to plot something using TikZ and pgfplots, however, when I try to plot a scatterplot and a function in the same figure, the function appears as a bar graph.
Here is the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=.7\textwidth,compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
        title = {Magnetic Field as a function of Current},
        ylabel = {$\mathrm{Magnetic Field}\ \mathbf{[mT]}$},
        xlabel = {$\mathrm{Current}\ \mathbf{[I]}$},
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        axis lines = left,
        enlarge x limits = true,
        enlarge y limits = true,
        legend pos=outer north east
    ]

\addplot [color=red, domain=0:2.2, mark=none]{0.00134681372549016+0.588954131652661*\x};

\addplot[
        scatter,
        only marks,
        scatter src=\thisrow{class},
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
            a={mark=o,green},
            b={mark=o,draw=red}% <-- don't add comma
        },
]   table[meta=label] {
    x   y   label
    0   -0.005  a
    0.1 0.069   a
    0.3 0.192   a
    0.5 0.301   a
    0.7 0.414   a
    0.9 0.54    a
    1.1 0.658   a
    1.3 0.767   a
    1.5 0.888   a
    1.7 1.008   a
    1.9 1.125   a
    2   1.186   a
    1.8 1.063   b
    1.6 0.933   b
    1.4 0.822   b
    1.2 0.697   b
    1   0.582   b
    0.8 0.461   b
    0.6 0.333   b
    0.4 0.233   b
    0.2 0.12    b
    0   -0.007  b
    0   0.001   a
    0.1 0.077   a
    0.3 0.186   a
    0.5 0.299   a
    0.7 0.418   a
    0.9 0.538   a
    1.1 0.648   a
    1.3 0.769   a
    1.5 0.892   a
    1.7 1.004   a
    1.9 1.12    a
    2   1.179   a
    1.8 1.07    b
    1.6 0.939   b
    1.4 0.821   b
    1.2 0.702   b
    1   0.58    b
    0.8 0.457   b
    0.6 0.339   b
    0.4 0.229   b
    0.2 0.124   b
    0   -0.009  b
    0   -0.004  a
    0.1 0.079   a
    0.3 0.19    a
    0.5 0.302   a
    0.7 0.422   a
    0.9 0.545   a
    1.1 0.657   a
    1.3 0.772   a
    1.5 0.894   a
    1.7 1.007   a
    1.9 1.119   a
    2   1.185   a
    1.8 1.057   b
    1.6 0.941   b
    1.4 0.819   b
    1.2 0.704   b
    1   0.576   b
    0.8 0.463   b
    0.6 0.341   b
    0.4 0.235   b
    0.2 0.127   b
    0   -0.001  b
    };
%\draw[color=orange] plot (\x,{0.589*(\x)+0.0013});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The resulting plot looks like this:


You were almost there: it's because you put ybar in the axis options. Remove it and your result will be fine:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=.7\textwidth,compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
        title = {Magnetic Field as a function of Current},
        ylabel = {$\mathrm{Magnetic Field}\ \mathbf{[mT]}$},
        xlabel = {$\mathrm{Current}\ \mathbf{[I]}$},
%        ybar,  % <<<<<<<<<<<
        ymin=0,
        axis lines = left,
        enlarge x limits = true,
        enlarge y limits = true,
        legend pos=outer north east
    ]

\addplot [color=red, domain=0:2.2, mark=none]{0.00134681372549016+0.588954131652661*\x};


\addplot[
        scatter,
        only marks,
        scatter src=\thisrow{class},
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
            a={mark=o,green},
            b={mark=o,draw=red}% <-- don't add comma
        },
]   table[meta=label] {
    x   y   label
    0   -0.005  a
    0.1 0.069   a
    0.3 0.192   a
    0.5 0.301   a
    0.7 0.414   a
    0.9 0.54    a
    1.1 0.658   a
    1.3 0.767   a
    1.5 0.888   a
    1.7 1.008   a
    1.9 1.125   a
    2   1.186   a
    1.8 1.063   b
    1.6 0.933   b
    1.4 0.822   b
    1.2 0.697   b
    1   0.582   b
    0.8 0.461   b
    0.6 0.333   b
    0.4 0.233   b
    0.2 0.12    b
    0   -0.007  b
    0   0.001   a
    0.1 0.077   a
    0.3 0.186   a
    0.5 0.299   a
    0.7 0.418   a
    0.9 0.538   a
    1.1 0.648   a
    1.3 0.769   a
    1.5 0.892   a
    1.7 1.004   a
    1.9 1.12    a
    2   1.179   a
    1.8 1.07    b
    1.6 0.939   b
    1.4 0.821   b
    1.2 0.702   b
    1   0.58    b
    0.8 0.457   b
    0.6 0.339   b
    0.4 0.229   b
    0.2 0.124   b
    0   -0.009  b
    0   -0.004  a
    0.1 0.079   a
    0.3 0.19    a
    0.5 0.302   a
    0.7 0.422   a
    0.9 0.545   a
    1.1 0.657   a
    1.3 0.772   a
    1.5 0.894   a
    1.7 1.007   a
    1.9 1.119   a
    2   1.185   a
    1.8 1.057   b
    1.6 0.941   b
    1.4 0.819   b
    1.2 0.704   b
    1   0.576   b
    0.8 0.463   b
    0.6 0.341   b
    0.4 0.235   b
    0.2 0.127   b
    0   -0.001  b
    };
%\draw[color=orange] plot (\x,{0.589*(\x)+0.0013});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thanks for the solution, I must've missed that option. I'm still figuring out tikz and pgfplots for now!

Thank you :) // No problem, we've all been there before ... As I said, you already came quite close: +1
